# MySQL functions as PDO parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table with `NOT NULL` columns, `NULL` columns, and `DEFAULT 'x'` columns. Now, I need to prepare a query in PDO which accepts values from `POST`, bind values with the parameters, and when there's nothing specified by user, binds `NULL` with parameters that allow it, and let the default values for ones that do not.

Here's a simplified code of what I'm trying to run:

```
$_POST['allow_null'] = null;
$_POST['not_null'] = "DEFAULT()";
$_POST['has_value'] = "Value";
$query = $db_connection->prepare("INSERT INTO my_table allow_null, not_null, has_value
VALUES (:allow_null, :not_null, :has_value)");
$query->execute($_POST);
```

I'm running into the weird problem of PDO inserting the string `"DEFAULT()"` as the value instead. Like this:

```
| allow_null | not_null | has_value |
+------------+----------+-----------+
| NULL       | DEFAULT()| Value     |
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: That's because PDO thinks you're trying to run a function. How exactly are you trying to insert it, show us the query.

Comment: @Fred-ii- OK. I've put a sample code in there.

Comment: Try `'DEFAULT()'`, however the way you're doing your insert `INSERT INTO my_table allow_null, not_null, has_value` that's as if you're trying to insert into 3 different tables; that's incorrect. I suggest you take a look at the manual http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: You may want to have your application change the query because passing the value default() through parameters will tell it to treat it as a string and not a function.

Comment: This `INSERT INTO my_table allow_null, not_null, has_value` needs to be `INSERT INTO my_table (allow_null, not_null, has_value)` having your columns set inside brackets. However, I'm confused by your question *"I'm running into the weird problem of PDO inserting the string "DEFAULT()" as the value instead."* - You're telling it to with `$_POST['not_null'] = "DEFAULT()";`, or what am I not grasping?

Comment: I'm avoiding being a sore loser here, but why exactly am I getting downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of bound parameters is that they can only ever be interpreted as strings (or null). It is impossible to pass in a function this way. You need to structure your query so that the only thing being inserted or changed is the string itself.

To get the default value in this way, you can use the [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function in your query, combined with the `DEFAULT()` function. Your SQL would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table 
    (allow_null, not_null, has_value)
    VALUES
    (:allow_null, IFNULL(:not_null, DEFAULT(not_null)), :has_value)
```

Then to get the default value, just pass null as the parameter.

Comment: I was researching while waiting for answers and found an answer exactly like this. Gonna answer this question myself but you beat me to it.